# Changing the default download name of my release branch in git

Tags: git, github

How would I go about changing the default name of the folder downloaded when a user selects the .zip or .tar file? I'm using a branch of my program for the release and would like to change the name of my folder. To give a little context

My [GitPage's](http://gmercer015.github.io/breadPull/) download link asks me if I want to download `Gmercer015-breadPull-8304d52`, though I would rather it just say `Aubp_v1.X`

Answer (score 1):

The link you are using in your page is to download as zipball/tarball of a revision (or a branch in your case) of your repository:

> [https://github.com/Gmercer015/breadPull/zipball/**release**](https://github.com/Gmercer015/breadPull/zipball/release) ("*release*" here is your branch name)

You can also replace the last part of the URL for a specific SHA1, like:

> [https://github.com/Gmercer015/breadPull/zipball/**4b622af**](https://github.com/Gmercer015/breadPull/zipball/4b622af)

But the thing is, this workflow is dedicated to get a *snapshot* of your repository, not a release *per se*.

To do a proper release and personalize your download you have to do two steps:

1. [Tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) the revision (commit) of the release.
2. Head over to [*New release*](https://github.com/Gmercer015/breadPull/releases/new) and create a release for your tag (with the download however you want).

GitHub is so nice that they also let you do both the tagging and the release in this one step; not to mention that they even implemented a *draft* functionality for this little corner (just like blogging).

You can read more about releasing your software on GitHub [here](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).